# How to use df.loc and if condtions in python pandas to delete a row

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to use the `if` condition and `df.loc[..]` to compare two values in the same column.
If the previous value is higher then next one, I want to delete the complete row.

This what I tried and my example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('cycle',[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]),
         ('A',[0.1,0.5,0.2,0.6,0.15,0.43,0.13,0.59]),
         ('B',[ 500, 600, 510,580,512,575,499,598]),
         ('time',[0.0,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.8]),]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(data)

df = df.drop(df.loc[i,'time']<df.loc[i-1,'time'].index)
print(df)
```

and I got the following error :

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and
>   'str'

Help is very is much appreciated

Comment: A sample of your input df and desired output df would help with diagnosing and advising. Please see: creating a [mcve]

Comment: I will check the answers and if there are not sufficient enough I am going to provide an example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df.time< df.time.shift()].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Attention: if one has duplicates in the index (several rows have the same index), this would also delete the duplicates. It would delete rows that do NOT fulfill the condition in the `loc` expression.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you are applying `.index` on the second df, before the comparison. You might try something like this:

```
df = df.drop((df.loc[i,'time'] < df.loc[i-1,'time']).index)
```

Comment: When I tried your solution I got the following error : 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Now that you've provided sample data to work with, it is much easier to test the code for your application. The way you've constructed your code attempt appears to require a loop. However, since @Loochie's answer already works, I'd recommend using that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pd.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Using `shift`:

```
df[df.time > df.time.shift()]
```

`df.time.shift` will return the original series where the index has been incremented by 1, so you are able to compare it to the original series. Each value will be compared to the one immediately below it. You can also set the `fill_value` parameter to determine the behavior of the first index:

```
df[df.time > df.time.shift(fill_value=0)]
```