# Deleting all rows that do not contain '1' or '8'

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like an awfully simple question but i cannot work it out.
I have a pd dataframe called 'df1' and I want to delete all rows where the 'breast_exitstat' number is not 1 or 8 - in other words the only numbers allowed in the breast_exitstat column are 1 or 8.

`df1 = df1.loc[~((df1['breast_exitstat'] == 1) | (df['breast_exitstat'] == 8))]`

This is currently the code I am using but it is 20 minutes into running and still hasn't finished.
I do have ~75000 rows but there must be a faster way to do this- am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure this is the line that's freezing? I've created a sample `df` with 75000 entries and code like this runs nearly instantly.

Comment: @Kraigolas - Oh that is interesting. I am running it on google colab, line by line and its definitely this part that is freezing.  I wonder what is going on then?

Comment: is it a typo?   df1['...'] == 1 | **df** ['...'] == 8.   should this both be `df1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df['breast_exitstat'].isin([1, 8])]
```

Answer (score 1):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304924/13424562):

```py
condition = ~((df1['breast_exitstat'] == 1) | (df['breast_exitstat'] == 8))
df1.drop(df1.loc[condition].index, inplace=True)
```